# Exporting RNA in extracellular vesicles (exosomes)?

Tags: rna, cell-signaling

I'm interested in how much is know about the process by which RNA is secreted from cells into extracellular vesicles.

Where is a good place to start reading about this?

How much is known about this pathway?

Can the pathway be engineered?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by searching google scholar for some good review articles (Nature Reviews and Annual Reviews are quite elaborate). A broad question like this is not suitable for the stackexchange format. If you can narrow down your question you can prevent it from being put on hold.

Comment: How can I make it more specific? Should I specify an organism?

Comment: No, specifying an organism would not help much. If your question was about specific points about the process of exosome formation then you can be directed to suitable paper. However, one can only suggest you to read a review on exosomal RNA. Your question about how much is known is also subjective. The third question: again, one can engineer anything but it may or may not be useful/productive. First, you are asking multiple questions and your questions are, moreover, too broad.

Comment: I just want to know if its possible for cells to be (genetically) engineered to produce a signal every time an mRNA is transcribed and have that signal exported into the extracellular environment.